# How do I add a watermark in A PDF and use the "Scale Relative to target Page"

Tags: adobe, scale, itext7

I am using an example based on the TransparentWatermark example in

http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/stamping-content-existing-pdfs/clone-watermark-examples

but I cannot seem to find a method or an option that correlates to the one in the Adobe settings with Add Watermark for "Scale Relative to target page".

Can someone point me to that?

Comment: You might want to specify the behavior you want instead of pointing towards features of other software products.

Comment: I WANT to scale the watermark I'm adding to 75% of the target page..

Comment: Get the dimensions of the page, scale the image or XObject to be 75% of that? I'll see if I got an example lying around .

Comment: I am doing Text not image if that makes a difference in this case.

Comment: It does, images is easier since they have convenience methods for scaling, also, what do you understand under 75%? Should the bounding box of the watermark cover 75% of the original page area, Should the length of the bounding box be 75% of the original page length? Same for width?

Comment: so if I do this in Adobe interface with the checkbox with regard to Text as well.. it does something by default adjusting the size of the font.  Do we know what that is?  i.e. I think this goes to your questions

Comment: Giving such details was what I meant when asking for a specification of the desired behavior...

Comment: sorry I thought it was somewhat obvious since the link I gave was specific to watermarking and using text to do.

Comment: @DavieDave a good stackoverflow questions includes all necessary information to solve the problem and does not link to outside sources whenever possible. It's also details the expected behaviour or problem without referring to other proprietary products. Good questions get answered more quickly and regularly, it is worth to put in the extra effort to explain everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had a go at creating a variant of the Textwatermark examples that scales the watermark to cover a percentage of the total page area. In essence, it's a linear algebra problem of finding the right scaling transformation and making sure all other translations and rotations are correct

```
package Stackoverflow.ScalingWatermark;

import com.itextpdf.io.IOException;
import com.itextpdf.io.font.FontConstants;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.color.Color;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.color.DeviceCmyk;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.events.Event;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.events.IEventHandler;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.events.PdfDocumentEvent;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFont;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFontFactory;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.AffineTransform;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfPage;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.canvas.PdfCanvas;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.xobject.PdfFormXObject;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;
import com.itextpdf.layout.border.SolidBorder;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.AreaBreak;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Div;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.layout.property.AreaBreakType;
import com.itextpdf.licensekey.LicenseKey;

import java.io.File;

public class ScalingWatermark {
    public static String DEST = "target/output/Stackoverflow/ScalingWatermark/output.pdf";
    public static String LICENSE = "src/test/resources/skeleton-itextkey.xml";
    public static String[] CONTENT = {"I have seen the face of sorrow", "She looks away in the distance",
            "Across all these bridges", "From whence I came",
            "And those spans, trussed and arched", "Hold up our lives as we go back again",
            "To how we thought then", "To how we thought we thought then",
            "I have seen sorrow's face", "But she is ever turned away",
            "And her words leave me blind", "Her eyes make me mute",
            "I do not understand what she says to me", "I do not know if to obey",
            "Or attempt a flood of tears", "I have seen her face",
            "She does not speak", "She does not weep",
            "She does not know me", "For I am but a stone fitted in place",
            "On the bridge where she walks", "―Lay of the Bridgeburners",
            "Toc the Younger"
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, java.io.IOException {
        LicenseKey.loadLicenseFile(LICENSE);
        File file = new File(DEST);
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        new ScalingWatermark().createPdf(DEST);
    }

    public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, java.io.IOException {
        PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(dest);
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer);
        Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);
        pdfDoc.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE,
                new TextWatermark());
        addContent(doc);
        doc.add(new AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.NEXT_PAGE));
        addContent(doc);
        doc.close();

    }

    private void addContent(Document doc) {
        Div div = new Div().setBorder(new SolidBorder(1));
        for (String line : CONTENT) {
            Paragraph p = new Paragraph(line).setMarginBottom(0).setMarginTop(0).setMarginLeft(5f);
            div.add(p);
        }
        doc.add(div);
    }


    protected class TextWatermark implements IEventHandler {

        Color lime, blue;
        PdfFont helvetica;

        protected TextWatermark() throws java.io.IOException {
            helvetica = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontConstants.HELVETICA);
            lime = new DeviceCmyk(0.208f, 0, 0.584f, 0);
            blue = new DeviceCmyk(0.445f, 0.0546f, 0, 0.0667f);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            PdfDocumentEvent docEvent = (PdfDocumentEvent) event;
            PdfDocument pdf = docEvent.getDocument();
            PdfPage page = docEvent.getPage();
            int pageNumber = pdf.getPageNumber(page);
            Rectangle pageSize = page.getPageSize();

            //Scale to a percentage of the page area
            float scalingAreaReq = pageNumber % 2 == 0 ? 0.75f : 0.50f;
            //Calculate scaling and x-y positioning
            float scalingFactor = (float) Math.sqrt(scalingAreaReq);
            AffineTransform scaleTf = new AffineTransform();
            //Calculation based on centering the watermark
            float xPos = ((1 - scalingFactor) * pageSize.getWidth()) / 2;
            float yPos = ((1 - scalingFactor) * pageSize.getHeight()) / 2;
            //Add translation to our transformation
            scaleTf.translate(xPos,yPos);
            //Add scaling to our transformation
            scaleTf.scale(scalingFactor, scalingFactor);

            //Use values from calculation
            PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page.newContentStreamBefore(), page.getResources(), pdf);
            PdfFormXObject watermarkAsXObject = createWatermarkXObject(pageNumber, pageSize, pdf);
            pdfCanvas.saveState()
                    //Apply scaling
                    .concatMatrix(scaleTf)
                    //Insert watermark
                    .addXObject(watermarkAsXObject, 0, 0)
                    .restoreState();

            pdfCanvas.release();
        }


        private PdfFormXObject createWatermarkXObject(int pageNumber, Rectangle bBox, PdfDocument pdfDoc) {
            PdfFormXObject xObject = new PdfFormXObject(bBox);
            PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(xObject, pdfDoc);
            int fontSize = 40;
            float margin = 100;

            //Paint the area that the watermark occupies
            pdfCanvas.saveState()
                    .setFillColor(pageNumber % 2 == 1 ? lime : blue)
                    .rectangle(bBox.getLeft(), bBox.getBottom(),
                            bBox.getWidth(), bBox.getHeight())
                    .fill().restoreState();

            //Translation and rotation to center the watermark text
            AffineTransform rotationAndTranslation = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(bBox.getWidth()/2- margin,bBox.getHeight()/2);
            AffineTransform rotation = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(Math.PI/4);
            rotationAndTranslation.concatenate(rotation);

            //Create the actual text
            pdfCanvas.saveState()
                    .beginText()
                    .setFontAndSize(helvetica, fontSize)
                    .setFillColor(pageNumber % 2 != 1 ? lime : blue)
                    .setTextMatrix(rotationAndTranslation)
                    .showText("Watermark")
                    .endText()
                    .restoreState();

            pdfCanvas.release();

            return xObject;

        }
    }
}
```